# How can I get the user to edit just a single line of text in ASP.Net VB?

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, content-management-system, admin

I'm looking to make a very simple, very small back-end system where the user can login and change/edit just one line of text on the homepage of his website, as he'll be changing it frequently.

I'm still relatively new to .Net VB but can someone point me in the right direction of what I need to study / read up on in order to achieve this? I know the line of text will need to be stored in a database, but just what exactly will need to be done in order to achieve this.

I can't imagine it being awful, awful difficult, as it's just a small line of text on the homepage. I imagine a full News system would be harder for example.

Would someone be so kind to tell me how I can do this and just what ASP.Net I need to read up on?

Thanks.

David.

Comment: I guess start with pretty much any introductory tutorial on ASP.NET.  Saving data to a database and displaying that data on a page is generally covered by any tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a simple ASP.NET website
2. Create a ado.net connection string
3. By using that connection string create a sql command
4. Then you can load the data into database

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tyr1YXpNOrk

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part4

Comment: Second link doesn't work, but thanks for the YT link and your input.

Answer (score 0):

Well. If you are looking for very basic, try below.

1. Create 2 keys in app settings within web.config file. 2 keys are your username and password.
2. Create login page and compare entered username and password with those keys. If those are correct, allow user to login. If it does not match, give an error message.
3. After login, you can allow user to change content.

Here you will have only 1 user, using which you can login into application.